# How do you set up a lane to snowball properly with creeps while you do something else?

Tags: league-of-legends

If a lane has equal creeps, what is the best amount of enemy creeps to kill and cause the lane to slow push/snowball creeps the best?

Answer (score 2):

In order to properly auto-push lanes, what you do is kill off the enemy ranged minions and leave the melee minions to tank your wave.  Due to their higher natural HP, they will survive long enough that you will stack a second wave onto the current one.  This can be done twice or three times if necessary to automatically push any lane.

This is different than simply last hitting or shoving the wave because your minions will take too much damage from the ranged caster minions and accordingly will not push as far or fast.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to snowball the lane so your creeps due to the enemy tower? That part is easy: just kill the whole wave, making sure you still get last hits. This is more commonly called "shoving" the lane. Do this before you leave the lane, to buy or gank, but only when you are sure you can do it safely.

If you want to slow push, then the only time you should damage an enemy creep is in order to get the gold from the last hit. Wait as long as possible before finishing it off. Your ad carry might hit for 200, but if you wait until a minion has 50 hp left you still get the gold while limiting your push.

Comment: no you don't get it not shoving or freezing say your team wants to slowly take down there mid towers as a group so you want to cause your top and bottom lane to slowly push in your favor up to there towers

Comment: @Illpalazzo gamei's right - you want to kill the minions. They only need to win one fight - as long as your team's minions win the skirmish, they will win the next, and then next, and so on until they reach the tower in a massive wave. If you want to build a snowball, just kill one wave. If you want to push with the minions, kill all the waves.

Comment: That is essentially the same as shoving. If you want to go mid, kill one wave both top and bottom and the lane is now in your minions' favor until either an enemy hero counters it or they get to the next enemy tower. This allows you to leave the lane alone for a few minutes at a time. However, if the enemy has super creeps in this lane it won't work as well. The super creeps beat regular creeps too quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how fast you want to push it, and when the tank minion shows up.

For instance, if you want it to push very very slow. Just kill one minion while all of yours are still up. You'll slowly push. Kill a second for a faster push. The best way to push though, is wait until the tank minion way, and just kill htat. Then they have only normals versus a tank, and you'll slow push the lane to the tower.